# JNI GetByteArrayElements strange behaviour

Tags: android, java-native-interface

Inside JNI part of my Android app I use following code

```
output_buffer = jni_env->NewByteArray(sizeof(short) * samples.size());  
jboolean *isCopy;
output_buffer_native = jni_env->GetByteArrayElements(output_buffer, isCopy);
```

This works OK on some phones, but on some other phones it crashes during call to `GetByteArrayElements`. After I change this line to

```
jni_env->GetByteArrayElements(output_buffer, nullptr);
```

the crash disappears. What could be the problem here?

Comment: You need `jboolean isCopy;` in the declaration, and `&isCopy` in the argument list.

Comment: You're currently passing an uninitialized `jboolean*` to `GetByteArrayElements`, so you're getting undefined behavior. See @user207421's comment for what you should do to fix this.